# Update multiple div from json file every sec without page flicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I wrote the script below to get values from a Json file that is stored inside a industrial automation equipment. The script is inside a HTML page that is stored in a PC and replaces Div contents based on its ID. Note: I can't run any code on the industrial equipment. This is not a "real server". It just stores Json files and update its values based in real sensors.

**Script inside index.html**

```
<script>
    function callback(json)
    {
        document.getElementById("Nro_Ensaio").innerHTML = json.Nro_Ensaio;
        document.getElementById("SP_Pelotas1").innerHTML = json.SP_Pelotas;
        document.getElementById("SP_Pelotas2").innerHTML = json.SP_Pelotas;
        document.getElementById("PV_Pelotas1").innerHTML = json.PV_Pelotas;
        document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = json.Status;
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.0.103/awp/VAR_PRENSAS/ensaio.json"></script>
```

**ensaio.json file**

```
callback({
    'Inicia': ':="ENSAIO".CMDS.LIBERA:',
    'Rearme': ':="ENSAIO".CMDS.RESET:',
    'Nro_Serie': ':="ENSAIO".Nro_Serie:',
    'Modelo': ':="ENSAIO".Modelo:',
    'Nro_Ensaio': ':="ENSAIO".Nro_Ensaio:',
    'Pronto': ':="ENSAIO".Pronto:',
    'Data': ':="ENSAIO".Data:',
    'Hora': ':="ENSAIO".Hora:',
    'SP_Pelotas': ':="ENSAIO".SP_Pelotas:',
    'PV_Pelotas': ':="ENSAIO".PV_Pelotas:',
    'Status': ':="ENSAIO".Status:'
});
```

When I open index.html in a browser I can view all values on the places that I really want, but I need a way to get this values refreshed. I tried to refresh the page using the script below, but div values flickers every time.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
//   -->
</script>
</head>
<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(5000);">
```

**How can I update div contents from the Json file every second without flickering the page?**
***Very important Information: I can't enable cross-domain requests on this "server".***

More information about creating pages for this equipment here! http://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/articletype/articleview/articleid/8567/siemens-s7-1200-web-server-tutorial--from-getting-started-to-html5-user-defined-pages
Thanks!

I tryed to do this script below.

```
    <script> 
    function callback(json)
    { 
    document.getElementById("Nro_Ensaio").innerHTML = json.Nro_Ensaio;
document.getElementById("SP_Pelotas1").innerHTML = json.SP_Pelotas;
document.getElementById("SP_Pelotas2").innerHTML = json.SP_Pelotas;
document.getElementById("PV_Pelotas1").innerHTML = json.PV_Pelotas;
document.getElementById("Status").innerHTML = json.Status; 
    }
    setInterval(callback,1000); 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="192.168.0.103/awp/VAR_PRENSAS/ensaio.json"></script>
```

**Ensaio.json Content**

```
callback({
    'Inicia': '0',
    'Rearme': '0',
    'Nro_Serie': '010',
    'Modelo': 'CPT001',
    'Nro_Ensaio': '138',
    'Pronto': '0',
    'Data': '18-07-2014',
    'Hora': '10-02',
    'SP_Pelotas': '40',
    'PV_Pelotas': '1',
    'Status': 'ENSAIO',
    'Nome': 'Test',
    'Descricao': 'Test1'    
});
```

Comment: Instead of updating the div constantly, why don't you check the file for changes. If the file contents have changed, then show a message to the user saying that and asking if they'd like to load the latest version.

Comment: Do you know how can I make this @mason? I'm very limited on js.

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery's `$.getJSON()` to load `ensaio.json` — then you wouldn't have to reload the page every 1s

Comment: If you want updates like this look into websockets and the pub sub pattern. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh201955.aspx

Comment: I can't use $.getJSON() because of Access-Control-Allow-Origin security. I can't allow this on the equipment @Foreign-object

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you can't. `$.getJSON()` lives on the client not the server. Try `jsonp`.

Comment: Because it requires a cross-domain request @ForeignObject

Comment: I can't use websockets because the equipment doesn't permit server side implementations

Comment: @Jay Blanchard, `jsonp` then.

Comment: OP: you should edit the original question to indicate that you can't enable cross-domain requests on your server.

Comment: Because there is no "real server" you cannot access the data as if it were. It would not accept HTTP requests needed by AJAX (leaving out requests to a URL for JSONP, etc.). If it is not a "real server", how is it accepting an HTTP request @RafaelMofati? #2 It isn't valid JSON

Comment: Also, to add to what @Jay Blanchard stated — if you can't change the server then it's most likely out of your control.

Comment: This equipment just stores the Json file in it's memory and replaces values like ":="DB".Name:" to its inputs values. Nothing more @JayBlanchard

Comment: If the `json` was _valid_ ( and this is a proper server ) you **might** be able to use a service like http://www.corsproxy.com to make a successful request.

Comment: It's not a JSON file. If there is no server the 'file' cannot be accessed via an HTTP request. @RafaelMofati

Comment: @ForeignObject I can't use this service because the equipment and the PC aren't on the internet.

Comment: UPDATE: It *is* a real server! Even if it isn't real JSON.

Comment: Please @JayBlanchard see this page. http://www.dmcinfo.com/latest-thinking/blog/articletype/articleview/articleid/8567/siemens-s7-1200-web-server-tutorial--from-getting-started-to-html5-user-defined-pages

Comment: I did @RafaelMofati I saw it when you updated the OP.

Comment: It serves just files like this "Json" file that I wrote above. @JayBlanchard

Comment: Although they named it with the JSON extension, it is not a JSON file and does not validate as JSON. Why do you only have 30k of space? Aren't you creating your files and using them from another server? Or are you actually creating HTML files on the embedded web server?

Comment: OK... But it is working @JayBlanchard! I can get values from this when the script runs, but I can't make the script reload this "json" file.

Comment: @JayBlanchard The equipment just have this memory size for page implementation

Comment: Have you checked into setInterval()? http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: So *you are* creating pages to be used on the embedded server, not on a stand-alone server somewhere else. You haven't been very clear about the setup which is what has caused us to ask all of these questions. @RafaelMofati

Comment: I've already tried setInterval() but I really don't know if I did this the right way @JayBlanchard. Can you try to rewrote the script for me?

Comment: Show us what you tried with setInterval().

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. Update your post with the edits.

Comment: Description updated @JayBlanchard

Comment: ensaio.json content added @JayBlanchard

Comment: You cannot get any of those items with getElementById(). The data in that file is formatted in such a way that makes the information unreadable. It is not properly formatted JSON, so you cannot deal with it that way. If I place this in a fiddle 'callback' comes back as undefined.

Comment: The only way that I have found to do this is to declare callback - http://jsfiddle.net/F8Rdy/ @RafaelMofati

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing the `src` attribute of the script tag in Javascript, but it seems as though the script tag needs to be replaced for the script to load. Here's a function that takes a script URI and an interval and then reloads the script indefinitely, without piling up a bunch of script tags:

```
var scriptLoader = (function () {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

    return function (scriptURI, interval) {
        var scriptElement = null;

        setInterval(function () {
            var newScriptElement = document.createElement('script');
            newScriptElement.type = 'text/javascript';
            newScriptElement.onerror = function (error) {
                throw new URIError('Could not load script ' + error.target.src);
            };

            if (scriptElement) {
                head.replaceChild(newScriptElement, scriptElement);
            } else {
                head.appendChild(newScriptElement);
            }
            newScriptElement.src = scriptURI;

            scriptElement = newScriptElement;
        }, interval);
    }
}());
```

It's used like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    scriptLoader("http://192.168.0.103/awp/VAR_PRENSAS/ensaio.json", 10000);
};
```

Answer (score -2):

[EDIT: this answer is only valid if you can set Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers on your server. also, my answer is *sans* jquery.] 
if i understand you correctly, the name for what you are trying to do is *asyncronous* http requests. that means that you want to get more information from a server without reloading the whole page. the javascript technology that is used to do so is called ajax or XHR. [here is an example](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first) of how to use ajax. you will want to replace the URL in `xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);` with the (complete) URL of the file on the server you want to access, i.e. `http://....`. the response that your requests gets from the server is stored in `xmlhttp.responseText` where `xmlhttp` is the name of the variable assigned to the ajax request.

[EDIT: in light of new information, maybe you'd prefer reloading an iframe than the whole page? not an awesome solution but iframes don't require cross-site request.]

Comment: @Rafael, nope. but see my most recent edit (at the bottom) - it's not ideal but it might suit your needs

Comment: I do have some iframes on this index page @danyamachine but, this equipment have low memory and I can't place more files inside it. I'm using CSS too

Comment: if his current script works the first time around, it's serving *something* so i'd bet on iframes working.

Comment: does your index.html live on the non-server too? if it lives on its own server, then your myiframe.html would live on your real server and just grab the same .json from you non-server as the code that you posted

Comment: iframes are excelent for my case but I realy have low memory. :(

Comment: even if you have to store the iframe.html on whatever has low memory (the non-server? or a real server?) it's still only an additional 5kb prob

Comment: @danyamachine I have only 30kb for all my pages.

Comment: I know what an iframe is @JayBlanchard. I have two off the working

Comment: in that case, you might be stuck with your flicker :p (but if space is so limited, i hope there isn't a big fat jquery file on there...everything you're doing can be pure JS.)

Comment: @JayBlanchard but we need to remember that I have other pages on that too